# Scala: Append only Some's to immutable list

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalaz, scala-cats

So say we're given a `List[String]` and bunch of `Option[String]'s` call them `a, b, c`. Say I want to append the valid (Some's) `Options[String]'s` out of `a, b, c` to my existing`List[String].` What would be the best way to go about this using immutable structures?

I.e. I know I could use a ListBuffer and do something like:

```
def foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String]) : ListBuffer[String] = {
    val existingList = new ListBuffer("hey")
    a.map(_ => existingList += _)
    b.map(_ => existingList += _)
    c.map(_ => existingList += _)
}
```

but I want to use immutable structures.

Comment: you can use cons (::) and create new immutables for each Options

Answer (score 4):

Use `.flatten` on a list of options and append it to your list

```
val existingList = List(1, 2, 3)
val a = Some(4)
val b = None
val c = Some(5)

val newList = existingList ::: List(a, b, c).flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String]): List[String] =
    List("hey") ++ a.toList ++ b.toList ++ c.toList
```

which is similar to `flatten` or `flatMap`.

```
scala> foo(Some("a"), None, Some("c"))
res1: List[String] = List(hey, a, c)
```

It's better to define a generic function like this:

```
def foo[T](xs: Option[T]*) : List[T] =
    xs.toList.flatten

scala> foo(Some("a"), None, Some("c"))
res2: List[String] = List(a, c)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let `val list = List("A", "B", "C")` and `val opts = = List(Some("X"), None, Some("Y"), None, Some("Z"))`. Then `list ++ opts.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)`  will give an new `List("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z")` with all elements from `list` and all non-empty elements of `opts`.

Comment: `list ++ opts.flatten`